# c#, Bluetooth get all in range paired undiscoverable devices

Tags: c#, bluetooth, 32feet

I have been quite a while on this problem. I was unable to detect undiscoverable devices in range. Yes, it is a safety precaution to make device undiscoverable, yet if device were paired wouldn't it be fair to allow detecting it while in range?

```
BluetoothClient client = new BluetoothClient();
BluetoothDeviceInfo[] devices = client.DiscoverDevices();
```

This is the code which does not provide needed functionality. I came across this [link.](http://www.codeitive.com/0JJqUWPVVW/detect-hiddennot-visible-bluetooth-device-on-mobile.html) It states that it is possible to get devices in range which you have MAC address of (which I would have).

1. Is it possible inside 32Feet.net library to discover an undiscoverable bluetooth devices and how?
2. To check if device I know MAC address of would be in range even in hidden mode and how?
3. To get undiscoverable paired devices in range and how?

P.S. I am so desperate that even malware like solutions would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading on topic let me realize that this can be done only with custom made bluetooth module (involves hardware making).

1. No, it is not possible to discover bluetooth devices inside 32Feet.net librabry.
2. MAC address would only help with custom made bluetooth module, with regular hardware this is not possible.
3. This is also not possible.

All in all, making a custom bluetooth module without required knowledge will take up too much time and effort for the task and it is not worth it.